# Record audio of headwords and definitions of entire Chinese-English dictionary

Tags: audio, audio-recording, audio-editing

I would like to make audio recordings of an [open source Chinese/English dictionary](https://cc-cedict.org).

I would like a separate audio file (i.e. wav or mp3 file) for each headword and a separate file for each definition of each headword. For instance, if the head word is 爱心 (aìxīn) then I will need a new recording of a Chinese native speaker saying that word. Then there would be 6 other separate audio recordings of a native English speaker speaking the 6 definitions:

1. compassion
2. kindness
3. care for others
4. love
5. charity (bazaar, golf day etc)
6. heart (the symbol ♥)

I want to keep the silent beginnings and endings of the recordings to a minimum while also keeping the manual editing of files to almost zero so that this project of over 100,000 headwords can be produced quickly and with low cost and manpower.

There is also the problem of naming these files in a way that would allow them to be accessed programmatically in the future.

What software has the features necessary to produce these recordings easily and/or quickly in high quality and low noise?

Any operating system is fine. Budget is not a consideration.

Comment: OK, thanks – reopened. Good luck then! For optimal recommendations, you might still want to name *preferences* (as I pointed out earlier). Up to you of course.